# How can passing data from ViewPagerAdapter to a different activity

Tags: android

I add to my app ViewPager to display a set of images I get the image from database.It works fine but I need to work (Intent) to image.So where user click on image he should go to a new activity and see that picture in it.I searched for a solution and could not find the solution.

If anyone Knew the solution help me please.

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private List<SliderUtils> sliderImg;
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;


    public ViewPagerAdapter(List sliderImg,Context context) {
        this.sliderImg = sliderImg;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return sliderImg.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {

        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, null);

        SliderUtils utils = sliderImg.get(position);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        imageLoader = CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();
        imageLoader.get(utils.getSliderImageUrl(), ImageLoader.getImageListener(imageView, R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round, android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert));


        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(position == 0){
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Slide 1 Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if(position == 1){
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Slide 2 Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Slide 3 Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });

        ViewPager vp = (ViewPager) container;
        vp.addView(view, 0);
        return view;

    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {

        ViewPager vp = (ViewPager) container;
        View view = (View) object;
        vp.removeView(view);

    }
}
```

```
public class FoodFregmaent extends Fragment {

    ViewPager viewPager;
    LinearLayout sliderDotspanel;
    private int dotscount;
    private ImageView[] dots;

    RequestQueue rq;
    List<SliderUtils> sliderImg;
    ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter;

    String request_url = "http://===========sliedshow.php";

    public FoodFregmaent() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_food_fregmaent, container, false);

        rq = CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance(getContext()).getRequestQueue();

        sliderImg = new ArrayList<>();

        viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

        sliderDotspanel = (LinearLayout)view. findViewById(R.id.SliderDots);

        sendRequest();


        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {

                for(int i = 0; i< dotscount; i++){
                    dots[i].setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext().getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.nonactive_dot));
                }

                dots[position].setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext().getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.active_dot));

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });






return view;

    }





    public void sendRequest(){

        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, request_url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                for(int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++){

                    SliderUtils sliderUtils = new SliderUtils();

                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                        sliderUtils.setSliderImageUrl(jsonObject.getString("imageurl"));

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    sliderImg.add(sliderUtils);

                }

                viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(sliderImg, getActivity());

                viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);

                dotscount = viewPagerAdapter.getCount();
                dots = new ImageView[dotscount];

                for(int i = 0; i < dotscount; i++){

                    dots[i] = new ImageView(getActivity());
                    dots[i].setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext().getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.nonactive_dot));

                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                    params.setMargins(8, 0, 8, 0);

                    sliderDotspanel.addView(dots[i], params);

                }

                dots[0].setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext().getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.ic_launcher_background));

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });

        CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance(getContext()).addToRequestQueue(jsonArrayRequest);
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MyTimerTask(), 2000, 4000);
    }
    public class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {

        @Override
        public void run() {

          getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    if(viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 0){
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
                    } else if(viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 1){
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
                    } else {
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
                    }

                }
            });

        }
    }

}
```

```
public class SliderUtils {

    String imageurl;

    public String getSliderImageUrl() {
        return imageurl;
    }

    public void setSliderImageUrl(String imageurl) {
        this.imageurl = imageurl;
    }
}
```

Still I search about solution to it

Comment: You need to pass it through the Intent when starting another activity. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23577964/13709773

Comment: I am a new application developer with little experience. This link is different from my project. Also he only transfers images in this way, what if he wants to transfer the text too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an `Intent` with a `String` that contains the image URL into your `view.setOnClickListener` within the `instantiateItem()` of the ViewPager

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {

    // ... Other code is omitted 

    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Activity2.class); // Change the name of the other activity
            intent.putExtra("url", sliderImg.get(position).getSliderImageUrl()); // add the image URL to  the other activity

        }
    });
```

And at the target activity, receive the url with

```
String url = getIntent().getStringExtra("url")
```